# Read bluetooth RSSI value using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, rssi

I want to get RSSI value using J2ME. How can I get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no API available for getting the `Bluetooth RSSI` value in Java ME.